# MEF and Prism - how to get hold of my modules at runtime?

Tags: prism, mef, modularity

My question may sound a bit stupid, but I can't work it out and still haven't found an online solution: 
I have a `DataAccess` module and an `EmployeesModule` which needs it. The `DataAccess` module is loaded when available and the `EmployeesModule` is loaded on demand. How can I use methods provided by the `DataAccess` module in my `EmployeesModule`?
I'm currently trying to use `ServiceLocator` but get the following exception:

```
Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IDataAccess, key ""
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: The exception should contain more that this error message. Please post the whole exception information.

Comment: Actually, it didn't. No inner exception or stack, beyond stating it comes from a MEF method (I don't remember its exact name and since it's now fixed, I don't have it). The problem was that I needed to add `Import` label to `EmployeesModule` and `Export` label to `IDataAccess`, in addition to its `ModuleExport` label. Thanks.

Comment: Noich: create an answer with this information and mark it as correct